# jquery javascript doesnt work in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi everybody and happy thanksgivingday !

i am some problem to include this script in codeigniter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?    application/views/jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('<?php $this->load->view('data');?>')
//im tryng also $('#show').load('<?php echo base_url();?>application/views/data.php') but it doesnt work anyway
        }, 3000);
    });


</script>
```

this function out codeigniter work without problem ?
maybe i have some problem in configuration file ?
idont know ... please write me sorry for the bad english
best regards

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya no error i dont know

Comment: Try and place the jquery scrip in your `<head></head>` area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url('application/views/jquery.js'); ?>">
```

In this case `$config['base_url']` has a trailing /

If you are trying to access files directly under applications/views you will get a 404 error. Is that your issue?

Normally you would put all your public side css and js files under a structure like...

```
Your Document Root Folder/
                         assets/
                               js/
                                  jquery.js
                               css/
```

So then you would have

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url('assets/js/jquery.js'); ?>">
```

And then you can access it correctly.

The trick is... view your HTML source code on the browser, view the link you have for your jquery and click on it and see what the nice error message says.

if it all works, then you will see the actual file source.

Comment: Updated my answer - with some debug... In short you are putting your js files in a location that is not directly accessible with a link!

Comment: GET http://localhost/airGym/application/views/jquery.js 403 (Forbidden) java:13
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Based upon my folder suggestions, it would be localhost/airgym/assets/js/jquery.js and that would work

Comment: i havent folder asset ... i must create or its a default folder ?

Comment: That would help if you created the folders, then move your files into their respective locations, then change the links appropriately.

Comment: maybe i have a problem with configuration ?

Comment: OK ITS WORKS ! but now i have this problem with this 

$('#show').load('<?php echo base_url();?>application/views/data.php')

in the consolle of the browser i get

GET http://localhost/airGym/application/views/data.php 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128984/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-riccardo-airone).

Answer (score 1):

seems your `src` is incorrect

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?    application/views/jquery.js">
```

try to change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"application/views/jquery.js">
```

Comment: Not sure you can get away with an uneven number of "

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot directly call any files which is inside of application folder.
Create a new folder **js** in your home directory and move your jquery.js into that i.e., **root_folder -> js -> jquery.js**
Then try this example

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('test');
    }

    public function hello()
    {
            $this->load->view('data');
    }
}
```

**View ( test.php )**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test project</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="show"> This content will replaced by your interval response </div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/hello');
            console.log('test');
        }, 3000);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**2nd view file ( data.php )**

```
<div class="hello">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```