# setInterval() does not works in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter-3

setInterval() function works perfectly on corePHP, but the function have no response in codeigniter. I want to get data from another controller without reload the page

**CONTROLLERS**

***home.php***

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{    
    public function index(){   
         $this->load->view('home_view');    
    }
}
?>
```

***new1.php***

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class New1 extends CI_Controller{
        public function index(){
            echo time()."-Time";
        }
    }
?>
```

***home_view.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendMail(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo site_url('new1/'); ?>",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  sendMail();
 setInterval(function(){ sendMail(); },2000);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="getdata"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: No error. When the button press, it print the value once. I want to get the values in each interval of time

Comment: Inside your `sendMail()` function body put a `console.log()` with some message and see what happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery javascript doesnt work in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796517/jquery-javascript-doesnt-work-in-codeigniter)

Comment: your javascript code is working fine. check if you have any issues with back-end 
https://codepen.io/chathurangao3/pen/EXLLXo

Comment: console.log('my message' + errorMessage); put this inside the sendMail() function, but result have no change

Comment: back-end is perfectly working, I think the setInterval() is not working

Comment: setInterval() function is perfectly working as you can see in my codepen link.

Comment: not a duplicate question, It's about AJAX

Comment: are you using routes in codeigniter

Comment: @Yasitha it works. But in codeigniter it have no response. I mentioned in my question it was works fine on corePHP

Comment: can you try removing last slash in this line
xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo site_url('new1'); ?>",false);

Comment: routes are not used

Comment: slash removed, but have no change

Comment: do you have auto load or load manually loaded url helper in codeigniter? unless if you use site_url you will get 500 error

Comment: auto load is used for url helper

Comment: @AdershPs did you check my answer?

Comment: yes, Thanks @Yasithan, It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is you are redirecting to a view file. you have to create a controller and function

home.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{    
    public function index(){   
         $this->load->view('home_view');    
    }
}
?>
```

home_view.php

```
<body>

        <div id="getdata"></div>
        <script>
            function sendMail() {
                 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo site_url('Ajax/sendmail'); ?>",false);
                 xmlhttp.send(null);
//                 console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
//                document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = Date();
                document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            //sendMail();
            setInterval(function () {
                sendMail();
            }, 2000);
        </script>
    </body>
```

Ajax.php (A controller page)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function sendmail()
    {
//      $this->load->view('y');
            echo  'testing';
    }
}
```

Also you have to set base_url in the config file.
config->config.php
set  $config['base_ulr'] to something like that

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';
```

Comment: thanks man, your code works.                                                                  It's not redirect to a view file, also into a controller, but the problem is due to calling the sendMail() before setInterval(). That was comment in your code, that is the problem. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: ah yes. I forgot to tell you that. :) anyway nice to hear that your problem got solved. If you can please accept as the answer